# Which dependencyManagement is setting my dependency version?

Tags: maven

i have a pom that has a number of entries in its `<dependencyManagement>` section.

How can i figure out which dependencyManagement entry is managing the versions of my dependancies!?

To further clarify my question, sometimes it is obvious -

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

, would manage this verion:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But what about dependencies that are declared (without a version) that dont match the groupId, etc.

Thanks

Comment: If something has `scope` equal `import`, then the content of that entry is imported, so you have to look inside `spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies` to find out.

Comment: Thanks but not what i was asking tbh. In the actual case i am looking at, i have ALOT of entries in the dependencyManagement section (import scopes and more), so how do i know which of those entries is managing my dependency? Also, to maybe clarify, my actual dependency is a Jackson one, which of course is v common

Comment: Usually by going into all those entries and reading them. Your IDE may help, though.